# Is the MCA(Multiple Correspondence Analysis) capable to deal with multi-valued qualititative varaibles?

Tags: statistics, data-mining, data-analysis

I am going to analyze a data set to find the variables more *interesting*, *important* and *significant* compared with others. Thus, the PCA, MCA and their extension FAMD (factor analysis of mixed data) come to my mind. But in my data set, there are not only the quantitative and qualitative variables, but also the multi-valued qualitative variables. For example, a product may have more than one colors. But for now , according to what i know, with the MCA, an individual can not belong more than 1 category of the same variable. Is there any solution or resources referred to this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: My approach to this problem would be to weight the assignment to each class (for instance using a mean) and then run a Multiple-factor analysis, that is nothing more than chained PCA instances (one for each sub-group, then another one merging the partial results).